# Spinner dropdown list height

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I m using a Custom array list for a spinner.
I would like to set the dropdown window height to 100 px. How can i do this?
Here is my adapter:

public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<String> klinikes_spinner) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, klinikes_spinner);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tspinner_row, parent, false);
        TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);
        label.setText(klinikes_spinner.get(position));


        return row;
    }
}
```